# Accessing the results array from sqlite3_get_table

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm using Ansi C and `sqlite3_get_table`; everything works except I can't access the query results vector passed as a pointer to an array. Here's my code...

```
char **sql_results;

sqlite3_get_table(open_database, sql_query,
        &sql_results, &RecordCount, &ColumnCount, &error_msg);

for (int i = 0; i <= (RecordCount + 1)* (ColumnCount); i++)
    printf("%10d %10s\n",i, sql_results[i]);  //get "EXC BAD ACCESS" message
```

How do I fix `sql_results[i]`? Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that this is only suitable for small tables, and that for large tables you're better off doing the query manually so you can do it step-by-step?

Answer (score 2):

I think this piece:

```
i <= (RecordCount + 1)* (ColumnCount)
```

is causing you the problems. Did you also try

```
i < (RecordCount + 1)* (ColumnCount)
```

Comment: +1: The other vaguely possible issue is that the value is UTF-8, but I think that's unlikely.

Comment: fyr.  Bingo! The loop was the problem as you suggested, not the variable.  I changed the test to only LT and it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the value returned by `sqlite3_get_table` is `SQLITE_OK`; it's not safe to access the result table if it isn't.

You should also be aware that this is a [deprecated](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_free_table) API. And you should add a call to `sqlite3_free_table` to release the memory; right now you appear to have a memory leak (or you've already done that, but declined to show us).

Comment: Good suggestions. I only showed the code I thought was relevant to the problem, but I did forget the free_table.  Thanks.